# Grouping data in R with including those attributes that are not on grouping condition

Tags: r

I want to group data such that i include those attributes that are not included in the grouping condition.
Example data

```
       pixel740 label num
1          0     0    4132
2          0     1    4684
3          0     2    4177
4          1     7    4
5          1     9    1
6          2     7   11
7          2     9    6
8          3     7   10
9          3     9    4
```

Result Data that i want

```
       pixel740     label  num
         0            1      4684 // this is as4684 is max num , so i include the row  
         1            7      4
         2            7      11
         3            7      10
```

i.e i want to include those rows that have max num according to pixel740 attribute

I have tried ddply,split options but they always include the attributes that we use to group i.e pixel 740 and don't include the whole row

How to do this? Is there a function that can do this or i use loops which i want to avoid

Comment: Why is sql tagged here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get the max `num` value for each value of `pixel740` with `aggregate` (calling your original data `x`):

```
aggregate(num ~ pixel740, data=x, FUN=max)
##   pixel740  num
## 1        0 4684
## 2        1    4
## 3        2   11
## 4        3   10
```

To get the rows, you can `merge` with the original set:

```
ag <- aggregate(num ~ pixel740, data=x, FUN=max)
res <- merge(ag, x)
res
##   pixel740  num label
## 1        0 4684     1
## 2        1    4     7
## 3        2   11     7
## 4        3   10     7
```

As requested in the comment, here's how to sort the data by the value of `pixel740`:

```
res[order(res$pixel740),]
```

For this short example, there is no difference in the output.

Comment: this is not what i want. i want the whole row corresponding to max num .i have shown the output that i want and the solution does not match it

Comment: no . i don't want max of label wrt to pixel740 but i want the whole row that corresponds to max num with pixel 740 as grouping condition

Comment: @user2143940 Click the check to mark the answer as accepted, if you like it.  (You can always change the tick to another answer if a better one comes along.)

Comment: 1 problem in that. The order in which data is arranged is completely hapahazard. can u suggest me how to order the data according to pixel 740

Comment: @user2143940 `aggregate` is returning results in an undesirable order?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to work out a solution using data.table, this i believe is the result. I imagine it can be improved.

```
require("data.table")
DT <- data.table(read.table("clipboard", header=T))

DT2 <- DT[, list(max_num = max(num)), by="pixel740"]

setkey(DT,num,pixel740)
setkey(DT2,max_num,pixel740)

RES <- DT[DT2,j=list(label)]
setkey(RES,pixel740)

RES

    num pixel740 label
1: 4684        0     1
2:    4        1     7
3:   11        2     7
4:   10        3     7
```

Comment: Whence comes the extra row?

Comment: I see now.  Having just `num` and `max_num` for the keys matched the wrong row with `num == 4` in the merge.  Base `merge` doesn't do this because it merges on all common column names by default.